# How to count the number of occurences of a class in multiple html files using js?

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a website that has the same class in various files. I want to create a js funtion that counts all the occurences and writes the total in an element whith a specific id. This is what I have so far:

```
function numMembers()
{
    var members = document.getElementById("members");
    var numMembers = document.getElementsByClassName("member").length;
    members.innerHTML = numMembers;
}
```

I've been messing arround with this and concluded that this only searches for the class "member" on my index.html file. I changed the class that I want to change to classes that only appear on index.html and the number was correct, so I guess this makes sence.

Comment: How are you running this code?

Comment: You cannot count the number of occurrences of a class in multiple HTML files using JS, it will only be able to count the occurrences of a class in the HTML file that calls the JS file, so even if the JS file is linked to other HTML files, it is only ever going to count the occurrences to that file.